# Is there a way to do the request header check using a decorator in FastAPI?

Tags: python, http, request, decorator, fastapi

I am currently looking at the examples of checking incoming request headers provided in [the FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/#extended-fastapi-app-file).

I am wondering if there is a way to implement the header check using a decorator over the routes, instead of repeating the checking code in every endpoint functions? Something like:

```py
def check_header_api_key(func, *args, **kwargs):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request: Request):
        if request.headers["SECRET"] != SECRET_KEY:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid client secret")
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@app.post("/course", response_model=schemas.Course, status_code=200)
@check_header_api_key
def create_course(course: schemas.CourseCreate, request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_course = crud.get_course(db, course=course)
    if db_course:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="This course has already been created.")
    return crud.create_course(db=db, course=course)
```

I am familiar how should I handle the parameters into the decorator, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of referring directly to the `app` object, you can create an `APIRouter` object, and add the dependency as a dependency for the whole router:

```
authenticated = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(get_authenticated_user)])
```

You can then add endpoints to this router:

```
@authenticated.post('/course', ....)
```

You can compose these router objects as you wish, either directly under your `app` - or as subrouters under each other:

```
app.include_router(authenticated)

# or with several sub routers:

authenticated_router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(get_authenticated_user)])
public_router = APIRouter()

authenticated_router.include_router(courses.authenticated)
authenticated_router.include_router(users.authenticated)
public_router.include_router(users.public)
app.include_router(authenticated_router)
app.include_router(public_router)
```

This way you can compose and move your routers around as necessary to make them require authentication or not, and you can further expand them into admin/private/etc. routers if necessary.

Comment: make question even more complicated

Answer (score 1):

Solved the same problem. FastAPI passes the `request` handler to `kwargs`. If you need to parse it your code should look the following way:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi import HTTPException

def check_header_api_key(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.headers.get("SECRET", None) != SECRET_KEY:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid client secret")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@app.post("/course", response_model=schemas.Course, status_code=200)
@check_header_api_key
def create_course(request: Request, course: schemas.CourseCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_course = crud.get_course(db, course=course)
    if db_course:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="This course has already been created.")
    return crud.create_course(db=db, course=course)
```